# 'double' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method

Tags: c#, winforms

Me and my teacher cannot figure this out. It's a windows forms app with all the appropriate fields linked, this is my only issue.

> Error  1   'double' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method

here's my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double total = 0; //total amount
        double tip = 0; //tip percentage
        double meal = 0; //meal amount

        tip = Convert.ToDouble(tip.Text) / 100;
        meal = Convert.ToDouble(meal.Text);
        total = (meal * tip);
        total.Text = "$ " + Convert.ToString(total);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to display the result into a Textbox; but Here in the code you declared `total` as double. please use the textbox name here (`total.Text`) in place of the variable `total`; And also use `.ToString()` instead of `.Text` inside your `Convert.ToDouble(`

Few more tips for you:

- use double.TryParse for converting string to double
- use `total.ToString("$#00.00");` to get the the number prefixed with a `$` symbol and rounded to `2` digits after the decimal

Let me assume the UI elements are :

```
 //txtTip be the Textbox for tip percentage
 //txtMeal be the Textbox for meal amount
  //txtTotal be the Textbox for Total Amount
```

Then your code will be like the following:

```
   double total = 0; //total amount
    double tip = 0; //tip percentage
    double meal = 0; //meal amount
      if(! double.TryParse(txtTip.Text,out tip))
      {
          // show conversion failed error
      }
       if(! double.TryParse(txtMeal.Text,out meal))
      {
          // show conversion failed error
      }
    tip = tip / 100;       
    total = (meal * tip);
    txtTotal.Text =total.ToString("$#00.00")  ;
```

Comment: Still nothing...

`       `private void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double total = 0; //total amount
            double tip = 0; //tip percentage
            double meal = 0; //meal amount

            tip = double.TryParse(tip.Text) / 100;
            meal = double.TryParse(meal.Text);
            total = (meal * tip);
            total.Text = "$ " + Convert.ToString(total);
        }`

Comment: Good, Let me know what you are trying to achieve with `Convert.ToDouble(tip.Text)` and also what are all the TextBoxes here;

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you named your class-level `Textboxes` the exact same as your method-scoped variables.  Or at least, that's my best assumption without knowing what your textboxes are actually called.

Your problem is you are trying to find a property `Text` on a `double`, which certainly does not exist.  If you actually did name your textboxes the same (which is legal in C#), you'll want to reference them by using `this.total` and `this.tip` when trying to set the `Text` property.

It's worth noting that I'm concerned for your education if your teacher is unable to debug this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a mistake of use local variable and global variable.

```
class Test
{
    // global variable.
    int va = 1;
    int vb = 2;

    public void local()
    {
        bool va = false;   // local variable
        Console.WriteLine(va);  // va is bool here.use local value.
        Console.WriteLine(vb); // vb is int, use global value.
    }
}
```

in your code, you declared local variables.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // declare local variables...
        // overwrite global varables.
        double total = 0; //total amount
        double tip = 0; //tip percentage
        double meal = 0; //meal amount

        // maybe, you want to invoke textbox.Text.
        // but, tip(TextBox) object is overwrote by double.
        // double has not the Text property, throw exception.
        tip = Convert.ToDouble(tip.Text) / 100; 
        meal = Convert.ToDouble(meal.Text);
        total = (meal * tip);
        total.Text = "$ " + Convert.ToString(total);
    }
}
```

how to fix it? just declare different variable name, like this:

```
private void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // make the local variable name is different with global.
    double d_total = 0; //total amount
    double d_tip = 0; //tip percentage
    double d_meal = 0; //meal amount

    d_tip = Convert.ToDouble(tip.Text) / 100;  // tip is TextBox here
    d_meal = Convert.ToDouble(meal.Text);
    d_total = (d_meal * d_tip);
    total.Text = "$ " + Convert.ToString(d_total);
}
```

or use `this` like this:

```
private void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double total = 0; //total amount
    double tip = 0; //tip percentage
    double meal = 0; //meal amount

    tip = Convert.ToDouble(this.tip.Text) / 100;
    meal = Convert.ToDouble(this.meal.Text);
    total = (meal * tip);
    this.total.Text = "$ " + Convert.ToString(total);
}
```